# jquery multiple selectors and 'and' operator

Tags: jquery

I need to enable the submit button when 2 fields have some value. I'm checking this using the following code:

```
var foo1 = $('input#foo1');
    var foo2 = $('input#foo2');
    $(foo1, foo2).on('input', function(){
        if((foo1.val().length < 1) && (foo2.val().length < 1 )){
            disableAdd('btnName');
        } else {
            enableAdd('btnName');
        }
    });
```

however if the length of foo2 is 0, it still enables the button. Also this only works when I start typing into foo1, not foo2

Comment: Have you tried simply using `$('input#foo1, input#foo2').on(…)` …?

Comment: thanks, that worked for the second issue. Do you know why the && is not working?

Comment: You probably want OR, not AND …

Comment: I want to check if both input fields have some values in them

Comment: Yes, and that is why you want to do something when there is _nothing_ in the first one, _or_ nothing in the other. You should go find a basic tutorial on how boolean logic works.